# Python calling Method in Windows cmd

Tags: windows, python-2.7, cmd

I have the following strange behavior:

I call a python-File (lets name it start.py), it calls another file:

```
import os
from time import sleep

os.chdir("C:\Path")
execfile('YYY.py')
```

In pythons Interpreter (Python shell) i uses execfile('start.py')
and everything works perfekt - the other file is started and works fine

If i run
`>_PATH_to_Python/python.exe start.py` in the cmd, python is started, start.py is executed, os.chdir("C:\Path") works, BUT the executed File YYY.py can't find my modules:

```
from myclass import ZZZ

ImportError no mudule named myclass
```

I have a empty `__init__.py` in my folder, didn't work. i'am inthe right folder(if i list files in my YYY.py, it lists my modules...)

I realy don't understand why it's not working, because in my opinion after calling the start.py there shouldn't be a difference between called from cmd or manually anymore

Comment: `execfile` doesn't add the script directory to `sys.path`. The `myclass` library should be properly installed, or at least use `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Okay i will check myclass and pythonpath. But dont you think its strange, that when i     execfile('start.py') it is working, but it is not if i start it via cmd?

Comment: Normally a script's directory is added to `sys.path`, which allows `import` to find modules and packages in the script directory. `execfile`, on the other hand, doesn't modify `sys.path`. You'd have to do that manually. That said, since Python 3 doesn't even have `execfile`, I think you'll be better off avoiding it entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay manged to solve the Problem (Thanks @eryksun for helping to actually understand the problem):

I just added `sys.path.append("C:\...\classes")` to my Python-Code (before calling my class) and it works perfect. It appends the Path to my class to the sys.path, where the Interpreter looks for Libraries.

Additionally my Gui always crashed, after it was started, so i added the -i Parameter

```
>_PATH_to_Python/python.exe -i start_prog.py
```

and look Python is started in interactive mode and everything is working.